# Why does my uploaded image not display?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am using PHP to upload a file. The upload seems to be successful. The $_FILES array is:

```
Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => mount.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/php61qYZj [error] => 0 [size] => 28947 ) )
```

Everything seems to be in order. However, when I do

```
echo '<img src="' . $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] . '" />';
```

it gives me a broken image.

This is so basic, how can it possibly be failing?

Comment: just check with `view HTML` browser's feature where your url points to (and always do that before you ask a question here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` is a temporary storage and works for only one request. It is not available from web as long as it usually located at OS directory for temporary files `/tmp`. You need to move the file to some permanent storage which is available form web.

Comment: I didn't realize that was a top-level /tmp. That would definitely not be available.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show a picture that has been saved in `/tmp`. You should move the file to a directory inside of the root of your web page.

Also see: [Tutorial on PHP-based file uploading](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move uploaded file to your image folder and then you can use this image to display in your browser.

**Example**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'/public_html/images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']))
```

the above code will upload your file to images directory then you can use this image.

for ajax file upload please contact me.